# How to make Plotly chart with year mapped to line color and months on x-axis

Tags: plotly

When looking at seasonal data I like to use charts that show a few years of data at once, with the months running from January to December on the x-axis and the values in the y-axis, using color to distinguish the years. This chart below was created in `R` using `ggplot2`. How can I replicate it or produce something very similar in Plotly using the Python API?

[image: ggplot2 chart]

So far the "best" I have done is this:

[image: Plotly]

...which clearly doesn't do the job. Ideally I want to be able to give Plotly five years of data (essentially the years provide the category) with an array of two or three or five colors and have it automatically map each year to a color without me having to manually specify the individual colors itself. Basically I just don't understand Plotly's color-mapping mechanism well enough to get there.

Code for Python example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

py.sign_in('xxx','xxx')

np.random.seed(123456)
num_periods=24
monthindex=pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=num_periods, freq='MS')
dd = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':monthindex,
                        'c1': np.random.uniform(10, 20, size=num_periods),
                        'c2': np.random.uniform(30, 40, size=num_periods)},
                  index=monthindex,
)
dd['year'] = dd['date'].dt.year
dd['monthname'] = dd['date'].dt.strftime('%b')

outdata = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=dd['monthname'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
        y=dd['c1'],
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend=True,
    title="'Stacking' years in plotly",
    xaxis=dict(
        type='category'
    )
)
```

Code for R example:

```
library(ggplot2)

dd <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"),
                     by = "month",
                     length.out = 24),
                 c1 = runif(24, min = 10, max = 20))

dd$month <- as.integer(strftime(dd$date, "%m"))
dd$year <- strftime(dd$date, "%Y")

xscale <- data.frame(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                     labels = c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
                         'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep',
                         'Oct','Nov','Dec'))


ggplot(dd, aes(month, c1)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = factor(year))) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = xscale$breaks,
                           labels = xscale$labels) +
            scale_colour_manual("year",values=c("Red","Blue")) +
                ggtitle("'Stacking' years in ggplot2")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just recently learned the pattern of making all the different traces I want to plot into columns in a dataframe:

```
dd = dd.pivot_table('c1', 'monthname', 'year')
py.iplot([{
    'x': dd.index,
    'y': dd[col],
    'name': col
}  for col in dd.columns])
```

The above code is convenient for plotting quickly, but if you want to change the default layout settings, you can do so with the more verbose version below. Check out https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#Style-Scatter-Plots for more examples.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

my_data = [{
    'x': dd.index,
    'y': dd[col],
    'name': col
}  for col in dd.columns]

my_layout = {'title':'my graphtitle',
          'xaxis':{'title':'x axis title'},
          'yaxis':{'title':'y axis title')
         }
fig = go.Figure(data=my_data, layout=my_layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='scatter_plot')
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use the `cufflinks` library which provides a simple plotting hook for pandas dataframes:

```
import cufflinks
dd = dd.pivot_table('c1', 'monthname', 'year')
dd.iplot()
```

`cufflinks` magically gives pandas dataframes (and other objects) the `.iplot()` method. Check out https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/ and https://plot.ly/pandas/

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this. I'm new to this library so I'm having difficulty working out whether your code actually uses `plotly` or whether it's using another plotting library; is `iplot` part of `plotly`?

Comment: Yes, it is using the `plotly` library. The first example depends only on `plotly` for plotting,  while the second one uses the `cufflinks` module to magically tie `pandas` and `plotly` together.

Comment: You can replace `iplot` with `plot` in the first example. `iplot` is for plotting inline in an ipython notebook.

Comment: I have tested it with real data and this works very well, many thanks. So much simpler than my own workaround.

Comment: Using the approach you give in the plot above, how would I control titles, axis formatting and so on? I have experimented with inserting various plotly formatting commands at various points after `py.iplot([{` but haven't managed to work it out yet.

Comment: editing my answer to include more information about the plot.ly python api